# ActionListener on JButton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button, actionlistener

Is it possible to add different ActionListener on different Buttons?
I have the problems that I have a JComboBox to set the difficulty level of my game and a button which should start the game.

So the question is how can i make it that I am able to select the difficulty level and then start the game by clicking on another button

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a "different ActionListener", you just need to obtain the result from the JComboBox inside the JButton's ActionListener, and use this result to determine what direction the program should go.

```
myButton.addActionListener(e -> {
    // get combo selection -- assuming that it holds Strings. Better if it held enums though
    String selection = (String) myCombo.getSelectedItem();
    
    // here use if blocks or a switch statement decide what to do
    if (selection.equals(foo)) {
        //....
    } else if (selection.equals(bar)) {
        //...
    } else if.....
});
```

I wouldn't even add a listener to the JComboBox, since the action will only start when the user selects the button.

Comment: But I have to know what the user selected in the JComboBox. It is important because I need the answer in another class

Comment: @Jens: and I showed you how to do it in my code above. If you need further help though ***you*** must show your pertinent code, and *show* where you're stuck. We can only help based on what you have shown us since we can't see code not shown. Preferably post a [mre] program in your question. Please read the link for the details.